# PHP problems with data recording in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have simple form:

```
   <form action="add.php" method="post" >
        <input  name="name"  maxlength="30"/><br/>
        <textarea  cols="80" name="description" rows="10">
        </textarea><br/>

        <table>
            <thead>
                   <tr>
                       <th></th>
                       <th width="200px">Shop list</th>
                   </tr>
            </thead>
             <tbody div class ="table">
            <?php
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT shop_id, name FROM shop") or die(mysql_error());
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo '<tr> 
                         <td>
                         <input type="checkbox" name="identifer[]" value="'.$row['shop_id'].'" /> <br /></td>  
                         <td>'.ucfirst($row['shop']).'</td> 
                      </tr>   ';    
                                                         }
                                            }
                  ?>

    </tbody></table>
<input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

I want to save the results in database in two different tables: *book* (book_id, name, description) and *places*. In *places* table I want to save shops where you can buy that book (places_id, book_id, shop_id).

I have add.php file (it's not working):

```
    <?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];



        $identifer =($_POST['identifer']);
        if (isset($identifer)){

            $id_arr = implode(',', $identifer);
            $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO places (places_id, book_id, shop_id) VALUES (NULL, NULL ($id_arr))") or die(mysql_error());

        }   




$q = "INSERT INTO baldas (book_id, name, description) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$description')";

$result2 = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_query());   

    ?>
```

I'm confused how I have to save results in two different tables in the same time, also I have problems with identifying which checkboxes are checked and to write the results in database, especially I have no idea how to deal with book_id.
Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have no idea how to deal with book_id

You would first insert the values into table `baldas`, then call [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

```
<?php
  $q = "INSERT INTO baldas (book_id, name, description) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$description')";
  $result = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_query());

  $bookID = mysql_insert_id();

  // CODE TO INSERT INTO `places` TABLE USING $bookID //
?>
```

> I have problems with identifying which checkboxes are checked

The way you have them, you'd have to loop through the `$_POST['identifier']` array to identify the shop_id

```
<?php
  foreach((array)$_POST['identifier'] as $shopID) { 
      $q2 = "INSERT INTO places (place_id, book_id, shop_id) VALUES (NULL, '$bookID', '$shopID')";    
      $result2 = mysql_query($q2) or die(mysql_error()); 
  }
?>
```

If it's not checked it won't show up in the `$_POST`

Comment: Thank you for fast response. But still I can do it right. :(


`foreach((array)$_POST['identifier'] as $shopID) {

$q2 = "INSERT INTO places (place_id, book_id, shop_id) VALUES (NULL, '$bookID', '$shopID')";
 $result2 = mysql_query($q2) or die(mysql_query());
  }`

This code gives 0 results. Did I miss something?

Comment: your die statement needs to be `mysql_error` . Maybe that will get you the error you're running into (because the INSERT looks good from the info we have so far)

Answer (score 1):

Try This, hope can help you:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $identifer[] =($_POST['identifer']);
    $y = null;
    if(count($identifer) > 1){
        foreach($identifer as $x){
            $y .= $x.",";
        }
        $val = rtrim($y,",");
    } else {
        $val = $identifer[0]
    }
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO places (places_id, book_id, shop_id) VALUES (NULL, NULL, '$val')") or die(mysql_error());

    $q = "INSERT INTO baldas (book_id, name, description) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$description')";

    $result2 = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_query());
?>
```

if places_id on table places and book_id on table baldas are AUTO_INCREMENT you can try this for add.php

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $identifer = $_POST['identifer'];
    $shop_id = null;
    if(isset($identifer)) $shop_id = implode(',', $identifer);
    $q = "INSERT INTO baldas (name, description) VALUES ('$name', '$description')";
    $result = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_query());
    $book_id = mysql_insert_id();
    $result2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO places (book_id, shop_id) VALUES ('$book_id', '$shop_id')") or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be the issue with setting IDs to NULL, if the IDs are auto-incrementing (which I suppose they are). Check that.

Showing errors is always helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The table that contains all the 'places' you can buy *a* book should have:

- **place_id** which is auto-incrementing and 'local' to that table. ID, unique.
- **book_id** is the id of the book from the books table (multiple rows with this will exist)
- **shop_id** is the id of the shop from the shops table (which you didn't mention)

There will be *one* row for each place a book can be bought. So you should only need one query if you are adding *one* place that *one* book can be purchased:

```
INSERT INTO places (book_id, shop_id) VALUES ($book_id, $shop_id)
```

Notice I did not include place_id, because that should be auto-incrementing.